# onClick() Function doesn't post any data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to post data in `onClick='fetchgfx()'` but it doesn't work.

I have tried `onClick='fetchgfx("+gfxname+")'` but it doesn't work. Then I tried to use `onClick='fetchgfx('name')'`. It also doesn't post anything in append case but in other hand out of this box it works fine.

What it will function and get the data here is the code:

```
function fetchgfx(){
            //document.getElementById('removegfx').scrollIntoview();remove();
            document.getElementById("bucketgfx").style.border="1px dashed #ccc";
            document.getElementById("expandGFX").style.display="block";
            document.getElementById("zoomGFX").style.display="block";
            document.getElementById("rotateGFX").style.display="block";
            document.getElementById("deleteGFX").style.display="block";
        }
```

And this function should have to send the value on top of function.

```
function insertgfx(e) {
   var gfxname = e;
   var sidescheck = document.getElementById("sidescheck").value;

   if (sidescheck == "front") {
     $(frontside).append("<div id='dragset'><img src='images/" + gfxname + "' width='100' id='bucketgfx' class='expandGFX zoomGFX rotateGFX deleteGFX' onClick='fetchgfx()'><i class='fa fa-expand' id='expandGFX' onclick='zoom(0.9)'></i><i class='fa fa-search-plus' id='zoomGFX' onclick='zoom(1.1)'></i><i class='fa fa-rotate-left' id='rotateGFX'></i><i class='fa fa-remove' id='deleteGFX' onClick='deletegfx();'></i></div>");
   } else {
     $(backside).append("<div id='dragset'><img src='images/" + gfxname + "' width='100' id='bucketgfx' class='expandGFX zoomGFX rotateGFX deleteGFX' onClick='fetchgfx()'><i class='fa fa-expand' id='expandGFX' onclick='zoom(0.9)'></i><i class='fa fa-search-plus' id='zoomGFX' onclick='zoom(1.1)'></i><i class='fa fa-rotate-left' id='rotateGFX'></i><i class='fa fa-remove' id='deleteGFX' onClick='deletegfx();'></i></div>");
   }
 }
```

Comment: and for posting data you have to use ajax @Hassan

Comment: The html code is written inside of append case.

Comment: Here is what it will function

Comment: Is `$(frontside)` a valid existing jQuery-object?

Comment: @HassanAli Please don't post code in comments, edit the question instead ...

Comment: Where is `frontside` and `backside` being defined?

Comment: frontside and backside is another function and working fine.

Comment: But what will i write in fetchgfx(HERE)??? to get the data from the append.

Comment: Right... but `frontside` and `backside` need to be HTML elements, that is where the HTML will be appended.  Also if `frontside` and `backside` were truly `functions` as you say they would require a, `()` .  Regardless you can't bind a function inside of a jquery selector.

Comment: Yes frontside and backsides are ok but i want to know how to write in fetchgfx(HERE) because it is in the append div so it never let me get the data

Comment: Somehow I highly doubt that, regardless you need to dumb down your question it makes virtually no sense, and the code you have posted barely resembles what you are trying to do.  How can you pass an arguement in `fetchgfx()` if your method doesn't even define an argument?

Comment: @NickDelaney Actually I want when click on onClick="fetchgfx('abc')" function fetchgfx(e){
     var gfxname = e;
     alert(gfxname);
} 
And it will show abc

Comment: But it doesn't work in Append and out of append it is working fine.

Comment: Half your problem is naming your arguments things like `e` and `abc` what is `abc`?  What is `e`?  It is horrible practice to do that, leave concatenation up to plugins like uglify.  You aren't doing yourself, or anyone else a favor by naming your stuff like that. Why are you even using onClick inside your html.  Just give it a class.  And create `click` event for the className.

Comment: It is an example sir.

Comment: In fact your function is working somehow: [example](https://jsfiddle.net/30u3rm87/), you can see the path of the image is dependent on the parameter of the function.

Comment: @empiric it's working cuz you actually defined an html element in the selector, and did it correctly.  Regardless HassanAli's problem is with the onClick inside his appended HTML.

Comment: Yes @empiric The function is working but when the image you put in fiddle you click on it then i want to post the id name on where i have set fetchgfx(HERE) so i can do anything with the name of id i just fetch but it never send id name in append case. may be some comma issue ' " + i want to know how to write to get the name of id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting the onClick inside HTML, just use an event trigger. I suggest switching body out with the element that the graphics are being inserted into for better performance.

```
$('body').on('click', '.expandGFX', function() {
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   fetchgfx(id);
});

function fetchgfx(id){
   //your logic here    
};
```

`id` can be any attribute within the html tag that you want.  Also you can't use `docuemntGetElementById` on a class name.  Honestly since you are using jquery, I wouldn't bother using `documentGetElementById` use the jquery `$(element)` selector.  Remember the way you select an element by it's `id` name is with `#` the way you select an element(s) by it's classname is `.` .

Fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/cq4304pd/4/

Comment: When i do alert(id); it says undefined?

Comment: With the code you post anything have to change in append div to get the data?

Comment: Look at my jsfiddle for an example, I've updated my post.  Keep in mind that an id name needs to be unqiue, and a class name can have multiples.

Comment: But Not in append case it is out of append.